# I can't show echo result using queues

Tags: laravel, queue, laravel-8, jobs, laravel-9

I initially tried using the code without queues and it worked fine. Since the execution took a long time to get the results I tried for my first time to use the queues.

These are the steps I did:

**Route:**

`Route::get('/getemail', [Controller::class, 'mail'])->name('email.get');`

**Controller:**

```
public function mail()
    {
        dispatch((new SendEmail()));
    }
```

**JOB: SendEmail**

```
public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }


 public function handle()
    {
        $oClient = EmailClient::account('default');
        $oClient->connect();
        $folders = $oClient->getFolders("INBOX")->first();
        $fatture = Invoice::all();
        $messages = $folders->query()->since(now()->subDays(300))->get();

        foreach ($messages as $message) {
            if (str_contains($message->getSubject(), "Ricevuta")) {
                //dd($message->getRawBody());
                $value = strstr($message->getRawBody(), "<NomeFile>");

                $result = substr($value, 10, 24);
                //echo $result .  "<br>";
                foreach ($fatture as $fattura) {
                    if ($fattura->nome_file == $result) {
                        echo $result . "<br>";
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

In particular, I want to retrieve some information from each email.

Since I display the results with echo, I notice that a blank page with no content is shown to me.

Since this is my first time using queues, can someone kindly tell me where is the problem please??

Thank you all!!!

Comment: You can't `echo`, `print_r` or anything similar on queues... the only way to see that would be on the queue worker (`php artisan queue:work`), but when you are on production, that command is usually being run by `supervisord`, so you will not want to output anything.... You have to store whatever you want in `logs` or a database or anything else, but with Laravel you do not `echo` anymore

Comment: @matiaslauriti ok i didn't know about this. How can I show $result? What do you suggest me? I would also like to have an answer and understand it

Comment: i have already previously tried to do `php artisan queue:work` and i get DONE

Answer (score -2):

Your route not properly define.

```
Route::get('/getemail', [ControllerName::class, 'mail'])->name('email.get');
```

Add controller dependency

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).